# Word wrap in TMemo at a plus (+) char

Tags: delphi, char, line-breaks

In my string i have an plus (+) char.

For example, string is

> __VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwULLTIwMTY5NDMyMDAPZBYCZg9kFgICAQ9kFgxmD2QWAmYPFgIeC18hSXRlbUNvdW50AgMWBgIBD2QWAmYPFQEiPG5vYnI+PHNwYW4+0JLRhdC+0LQ8L3NwYW4+PC9ub2JyPmQCAw9kFgJmDxUBTDxub2JyPjxhIGhyZWY9J3NpZ251cC5hc3B4JyB0YXJnZXQ9J19zZWxmJz7QoNC10LPQuNGB0YLRgNCw0YbQuNGPPC9hPjwvbm9icj5kAgUPZBYCZg8VAUk8bm9icj48YSBocmVmPSdhYm91dC5hc3B4JyB0YXJnZXQ9J19zZWxmJz7QmNC90YTQvtGA0LzQsNGG0LjRjzwvYT48L25vYnI+ZAICD2QWBAIBDxYCHwACBRYKZg9kFgJmDxUBHjxsaT48Yj7QmtC

Now i add line to memo1 and get this:

[image: WTF]

Delphi inserts new line at random places.
I`m try to remove all lines break:

```
viewstate:=StringReplace(viewstate, #10#13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
viewstate:=StringReplace(viewstate, #13#10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
viewstate:=StringReplace(viewstate, #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
viewstate:=StringReplace(viewstate, #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

But it`s no result. What is it?

P.S. I`m from Russia, so sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi isn't adding linebreaks. The memo is adding visual soft-breaks at separator characters (such as `+`). Set the memo's `WordWrap` property to false and it should resolve the problem.

Comment: Setting wordwrap to false adds horizontal scrollbar, but linebreaks don`t removes :)

Comment: There is still a limit to the length of a memo line, dependent on your OS. On XP, the limit appears to be 4096 characters. The important point here is that there isn't actually a linefeed being inserted, it's simply a visual display issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, to wrap text on a specific character you can use the

`WrapText()` function in the SysUtils.pas unit.

```
function WrapText(const Line, BreakStr: string; const BreakChars: TSysCharSet;
  MaxCol: Integer): string;
```

For example:

```
sOutput := WrapText(sInput,#13#10,['+'],100);
```